# Reboot the phone and connection refused :(

Tags: android

I am facing problem with my app.My app has the auto-started function and it always listens a broadcast named 'BOOT_COMPLETED'.
I want to do a loop request in my custom Service(startService) every 5 seconds.When i launch the app,everything seems to look good.

When i reboot my phone,the problem is coming.Because the app can autostart,i will do nothing and just watch the log.
[this the fail log pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjWPI.png)

Only the first request will be successful,others all  failed(org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.27.46:8090 refused).But when I click the app icon to launch it,it turns good that every request is successful.

I cant solve the problem, pls help me :)

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(BOOT_ACTION) || intent.getAction().equals(QUICKBOOT_ACTION) || intent.getAction().equals(REBOOT_ACTION)) {
        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent();
        mainActivityIntent.setAction("GrayService");
        mainActivityIntent.setPackage("com.wyk.accessibilityservicewx");
        context.startService(mainActivityIntent);
    }
}


try {
    String uriAPI = "http://10.0.27.46:8090/crm/insert_customer_resource.json";
    HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(uriAPI);
    List < NameValuePair > params = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("str", "I am Post String"));
    httpRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpRequest);
    if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        String strResult = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        LogUtil.log("====success:" + strResult);
    } else {
        LogUtil.log("====fail code:" + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    LogUtil.log("====fail code:" + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: What about connection closing after each request?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.The problem casued by my phone system(XiaoMi).I should allow my app to autostart from setting.